# Power Query - Join multiple tables

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I know, this is something that should be done at the level of the data model as a star Schema but in this specific case it is not possible.
I have 1 dimensional table and 4 transactional tables. All of them have the 1 unique column (order number).
Is there any way to get 1 huge table without joining them together step by step and expanding them?
Is there a way to do it all in one step?

In the future this will be done in the Warehouse but for now this will work as a proof of concept for several months.

Comment: What do you mean by "1 unique code"? A different column? A different value in the same column? Sample data would help.

Comment: Sorry, I mean 1 unique column. Like the order number. This column is listed in every table

Comment: Do the the transactional tables have the same columns? I'm thinking you should be appending not merging the tables. Then possibly do a Group By if you need to combine rows.

Comment: No, the tables contain different values for each order. Instead of building a star Schema within power bi I would like to build a flat file in power query.

Comment: You can build flat files in Power BI but in general, it's a horrible idea. Performance will be worse, file sizes will be significantly bigger, and there are things you won't be able to do in DAX without a proper star schema. It does have valid use cases, such as building a file in Excel that is used in another process.

Comment: I don't understand your concern about wanting to do it all in one step. You can overload steps in Power Query, but in general, this makes queries hard to support and does nothing for performance. If you paste in your query or show sample data, it would be easier to provide better guidance.